# Summing values based on multiple criteria. Columns are different sizes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet (Test Sheet 2) with two sheets in it, Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.  Sheet 2 is where all of the data is and I need to get the sums of the counts of that column based on three criteria into sheet 1 column C.  The name, week, year and count need to match up.  I used the formula

```
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(A2:A&2020&B2:B, {Sheet2!A2:A&Sheet2!B2:B&Sheet2!C2:C, Sheet2!D2:D}, 2, FALSE)))
```

but that only works for unique rows.  In the example sheet I am providing, the formula works well for Bill, Lisa, Katie and Jon because they all have one value for 'count' from Sheet2 when the parameters of name, week and year match up.  But Mike has two rows matching the criteria.  This formula returns the first match which is 3.  The other value is 4 so I would like the count in Sheet1 to show 7 instead of 3.  I need it to add them up.

I also tried to use sumifs but the columns are two different sizes so that didn't work.

Any idea? I did try to combine sumif with the above formula but that did not work either.

[Link to Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f2AnjS6x9axgyPz-FSem8JBYrzRW6D1VnnRnrn6tlC0/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Hello, what do you mean the columns are two different sizes? Can you give an example of this?

Comment: yeah sure.  One of the formulas I try using is =sumifs(Sheet2!D2:D, A2:A = Sheet2!A2:A, Sheet2!B2:B = 2020, B2:B, Sheet2!C2:C)  but I get the error "Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size." because the array columns in Sheet 2 are 6 rows while the columns in Sheet1 are 5 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution with ARRAYFORMULA and SUMIF

If you need to use ARRAYFORMULA to improve the performances you can use this tweak of the `SUMIF` statement: basically you can concatenate the conditions to make them create a single `AND` condition.

This would be a possible solution for the formula in your comment:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(Sheet2!A2:A&Sheet2!B2:B,A2:A&2020,Sheet2!D2:D))
```

### Solution with SUMIFS

If you are looking for a solution with the `SUMIFS` formula you can use this:

```
SUMIFS('sum_range', 'criteria_range', condition, ['criteria_range_2', condition_2])
```

In your case this will translate to:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!D2:D, Sheet2!A2:A, A2, Sheet2!B2:B, 2020)
```

In this case the ranges dimensions won't affect the formula execution.
Just drag this formula for the Sheet1 table column and you will get the results. The drawback is that you cannot use `ARRAYFORMULA` with `SUMIFS`. Performance wise, if you have a lot of rows in the `Sheet1` I suggest using the `ARRAYFORMULA` solution, since this will trigger a lot of formula calls instead of just one.

Comment: Hey yeah I am trying to use it with an arrayformula since there are many many cells.

Comment: I see, Arrayformula cannot be used with `SUMIFS`. But you can use Arrayformula with `SUMIF`. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query()

```
=query(Sheet2!A:D, "Select A, C, sum(D) where B = 2020 group by A, C label C 'Week', sum(D) 'Count'", 1)
```

UPDATED:

If you really need to use vlookup in arrayformula() you can always ise the query (that deals with the summing) as the lookup range. In the spreadsheet I used

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), iferror(vlookup(A2:A&year(D2:D)&E2:E, query({Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B&Sheet2!C:C, Sheet2!D:D}, "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1", 1), 2, 0)),) )
```

and see if that helps?

[image]

Comment: That works but only for this particular example.  The sheet I am trying to use this formula in is much larger with 1000s of rows and dozens of columns.  I just made the test have fewer rows and columns to show what I need to do.

Comment: I provided an answer for the dataset you posted. I do not (can not) know how 'realistic' this dataset is compared to the original one, but I do know that query() is a very powerful tool that is able to provide solutions in a lot of cases.

Comment: I was able to use query to get results but my worry is that if every cell is using the query function, the sheet will eventually slow down as there are 50,000+ cells.  That is why I was trying to do something with arrayformula

Comment: One query in every cell ? The output in the example I posted uses only one formula ...

Comment: Updated my answer with a vlookup solution (using query).

Comment: Hi I updated the Sheets to reflect more of what I am working with.  Please let me know if I can clarify further.  Thanks a ton for your help

Comment: Updated my formula in my post. Check cell F2 in the spreadsheet you shared.

Comment: I don't know which column you want to use for the year() part. In my present formula I used column D. If that needs to be column B, change year(D2:D) to year(B2:B).